# How many sets of four points in an MxN grid have one point contained by three other points?

Tags: geometry, algorithms, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry

Given a 3x3 grid:

```
1 2 3
8 9 4
7 6 5
```

We find 126 distinct sets of 4 points $$\binom{9}{4}$$

There are 8 cases such that when the points are connected with a line in clockwise direction, one point (in this case, `9`) is contained by angle formed from joining the other three points with a line:

```
{1,3,6,9}, {1,4,6,9}, {1,4,7,9}, {2,4,7,9},

{2,5,7,9}, {2,5,8,9}, {3,5,8,9}, {3,6,8,9}.
```

i.e.[image], where {1,4,7,9} contains 9.

For a grid of any m and n, how can we determine the number of sets for which such a condition holds? So, the number of sets across all $$\binom{mn}{4}$$

Where one point is inside angle formed by connecting the other 3 members of the set.

Comment: What _exactly_ do you mean when you say one is contained by the other three?

Comment: Updated answer, adding illustration @Arthur

Comment: Do you want the answer for a specific fixed "middle" element in your $m \times n$ grid, or do you want the sum of counts of all solutions over all choices for "middle" element? And if the latter, what if a triangle contains more than one "middle" point? Do you want that to just count as 1, or do you want to multiply by the number of middle points?

Comment: So you want the number of sets of four points in a rectangular grid that don't make a convex (degenerate?) quadrilateral?

Comment: @Arthur Based on the example, it seems like the "middle point" must be in the strict interior, e.g. (2,4,6,9) wasn't listed as a solution.

Comment: Yes, middle point must be in the strict interior, not on a line that would close the triangle.

Comment: @user2566092 Question has been updated

Comment: @Arthur I'm computing the number of sets of four points in a rectangular grid that *can* produce a complex quadrilateral.

Comment: @CalvinFroedge Sorry one last comment, don't you mean ${{mn} \choose 4}$ sets, instead of $n \choose 4$?

Comment: @user2566092 Good catch! I meant the number of vertices.

Answer (score 0):

Pick's theorem will tell you for a grid how many interior grid points you have inside a given triangle, in terms of the volume (easy to compute) and number of boundary points on the triangle (also easy to compute by computing for each side, the GCD of coordinates of the vector connecting one vertex to another). Also the answer is translation and rotation and reflection invariant since you are working on a grid. So this reduces a seemingly ${{mn} \choose 4}$ complexity calculation to one that is $O({{mn} \choose 2})$, basically by assuming one vertex is $(1,1)$ and the other vertices are in the upper-right. It's still not as good as an explicit formula but it can at least handle values of $mn$ that are the square of the values of $mn$ that you could previously handle by brute force.

Comment: Well, you don't have to do every choice of ${{mn} \choose 3}$ triangles, based on the symmetries, but yes, basically you have to do $O({{mn} \choose 2})$ triangles this way and evaluate them individually and then multiply by the number of similar triangles you can get by translation/rotation/reflection. So it won't scale forever without a more explicit formula, but at least you can solve bigger cases than brute force. And even without symmetries, you can count the number of interior points for each of the ${{mn} \choose 3}$ triangles easily with Pick's theorem.

Comment: Any ideas how to develop an explicit formula? Do you think one exists or is possible?

Comment: Is it fair to say there will be a recurrence relation between the size of the grid and the number of triangles with interior grid points?

Comment: @CalvinFroedge I'm not sure. If you increase $m$ or $n$ then it's possible you'll get new triangles with interior points where the new triangles have side slopes that weren't possible for previous $m$ and $n$. I have to think more, but I'm guessing this problem is fairly hard.

Comment: @CalvinFroedge I'd recommend setting $m = n$ and brute forcing the answer for a decent number of values of $n$ and then checking the sequence of counts you get against the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences (OEIS).